# KnockoutJS foreach doesn't iterate through collection

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, foreach, knockout-2.0

For some reason, `foreach` in [Knockout.js](https://knockoutjs.com/) doesn't iterate through my observable array.

In my HTML I have this which works perfectly fine with the observable model:

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label class="popup-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <span class="email" data-bind="text: masterVM.employeeVM.Email"></span>
</div>
```

But in the same model, this code doesn't work:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: masterVM.employeeVM.Tags, as: 'tag' }">
    <li>
        <span class="popup-tag" data-bind="text: tag.tagName"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are two models:

**Employee**

```
var observableEmployee = function(id, email, tags) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Email = ko.observable(email); 

    self.Tags = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(tags, function(item) {
        return new observableTag(item.Id, item.EmployeeId, item.TagId, item.tagName)
    }));

    self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, {
        deep: true
    });

    self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.errors().length > 0 ? false : true;
    });
}
```

and **Tag**

```
var observableTag = function(id, employeeId, tagId, tagName) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.employeeId = ko.observable(employeeId);
    self.tagId = ko.observable(tagId);
    self.TagName = ko.observable(tagName);

    self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, {
        live: true
    });

    self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.errors().length > 0 ? false : true;
    });
}
```

and handler function:

```
var employeeHandler = function () {
var self = this;

self.getEmployeeDetails = function (header) {
    $.ajax({
        url: masterVM.controller.renderEmployeeDetails,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: header.data("employeeid") }),
        success: function (result) {                

            masterVM.employeeVM = new observableEmployee(
                result.model.Id,
                result.model.Email,
                result.model.Tags
            );
            ko.applyBindings(masterVM, $("#employee-planning-selected")[0]);

            //header.parent().addClass('open');
            //header.next().slideDown('normal');

            //hideLoader(header);
            console.log('get employee details');
            $(document).on('click', "div.employee", onNameCardClick);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });

}}
```

In my HTML file

```
    <script>
        masterVM = {
            controller: {
                renderEmployeeDetails: '@(Html.GetActionUrl<EmployeesController>(c => c.RenderEmployeeDetails(0)))'
            },
            employeeHandler: new employeeHandler(),
            employeeVM: new observableEmployee(0, '', '', '', '')
    }
    ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
</script>
```

Tried something like this, and still nothing

```
<!--ko foreach: employeeVM.Tags -->
    <span data-bind="text: $data.Tags"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And no, **there are no errors in the console**, I have used KnockouJS context debugger which shows me that there are elements in this collection, even when I try to display them as an object it shows me a list of 4 elements.

Knockout version: 2.3.0

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but in your binding you're using camel-case for tag.tagName, but in your tag model TagName is pascal-case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but actually it was correctly typed in my code (pascal convention), but still didn't work. However, adiga solution posted by adiga below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**. If you are binding `masterVM` object in `ko.applyBindings(masterVM)`, you don't need to specify that object again in your data-bindings.

So, it should be

```
foreach: { data: employeeVM.Tags, as: 'tag' }
```

And not

```
foreach: { data: masterVM.employeeVM.Tags, as: 'tag' }
```

(I'm not sure how the first `data-bind="text: masterVM.employeeVM.Email"` is working)

**2)**. You don't need to call `applyBindings` more than once. If you want to update the employee object, you can turn your `employeeVM` into an observable and keep updating it inside `getEmployeeDetails` method.

**3)** Your [*containerless control flow syntax*](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-4-using-foreach-without-a-container-element) won't work. (`<!--ko foreach: employeeVM.Tags -->`). Inside this foreach, `$data` is the current `Tag` object [in context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). So, it should be `<span data-bind="text: $data.TagName"></span>`

Here's a minimal version of the code. Click on "Run code snippet" to test it. When you click on `Update employee` button, I'm updating the `employeeVM` observable and the data gets rendered again. Without calling `applyBindings` again

```js
var employeeHandler = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.getEmployeeDetails = function(header) {
    var newEmployee = new observableEmployee(0, 'newEmployee@xyz.com', [{
      Id: 3,
      EmployeeId: 3,
      TagId: 3,
      tagName: 'Tag Name 3'
    }]);
  
   // You need to use employeeVM(newEmployee) instead of employeeVM = newEmployee
   // Because employeeVM is an observable.
    masterVM.employeeVM(newEmployee);
  }
}

var observableEmployee = function(id, email, tags) {
  var self = this;

  self.Id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Email = ko.observable(email);

  self.Tags = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(tags, function(item) {
    return new observableTag(item.Id, item.EmployeeId, item.TagId, item.tagName)
  }));
}

var observableTag = function(id, employeeId, tagId, tagName) {
  var self = this;

  self.Id = ko.observable(id);
  self.employeeId = ko.observable(employeeId);
  self.tagId = ko.observable(tagId);
  self.TagName = ko.observable(tagName);
}

var masterVM = {
  controller: {
    renderEmployeeDetails: ''
  },
  employeeHandler: new employeeHandler(),
  // change this to an observable
  employeeVM: ko.observable(new observableEmployee(0, 'abc@xyz.com', [{
    Id: 1,
    EmployeeId: 1,
    TagId: 1,
    tagName: 'Tag name 1'
  }]))
}

ko.applyBindings(masterVM);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  masterVM.employeeHandler.getEmployeeDetails()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="field-group">
  <label class="popup-label" for="email">Email:</label>
  <span class="email" data-bind="text: employeeVM().Email"></span>
</div>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: employeeVM().Tags, as: 'tag' }">
  <li>
    <span class="popup-tag" data-bind="text: tag.employeeId"></span> <br>
    <span class="popup-tag" data-bind="text: tag.tagId"></span><br>
    <span class="popup-tag" data-bind="text: tag.TagName"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="button">Update employee</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turning employeeVM into an observable really helped and solved my problem. So that was the issue.